# Magento custom module setup script, add pre-fix

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql

For my custom module I create a database table with the magento sql setups script.
The problem is that if the magento installation has a prefix on the database it doesn't add the prefix. So the table is created but without the needed prefix.

Anybody knows how I can add this to my script?

Comment: please add your script to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->getTable('yourmodule_table')` in your sql script. The reference `yourmodule_table` should match what you have defined as a table in your config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

suppose if your module is `yourmodule` and the table name is `yourtablename`, so in the `app/code/local/yourcompmay/yourmodule/etc/config.xml` file of this module, the resource entity tag will look like:

```
  <entities>
     <yourtable1> <!-- this is the reference of the table -->
          <table>yourtablename</table> <!--enter the actual table name within these table tags-->
    </yourtable1>
  </entities>
```

now you can call the table by reference by using the following code in setup files:

```
$this->getTable('module / table reference');
```

if I use above exampled values, it will become `$this->getTable('yourmodule/yourtable1');`, this will return the table name (with prefix if any).

Answer (score 1):

You tried this?

```
$prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
echo $prefix;
```

While creating table in script file add $prefix to the table name.

Hope this will help you:)